# Plot a line between prediction and ground_truth point in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, prediction

I have two dataframes, ground_truth and prediction (Both are pandas series). Finally, I want to plot all **prediction points** and all **ground_truth points** as I already did. What I wanna do, is to **plot a line between** each prediction and ground_truth point. So that the line is a connection between the prediction point x1,y1 and the ground_truth point x2,y2. For a better understanding I attached an image. The black lines (created via paint) is what I want to do. [image: example]

This is what I already have:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(pred,'ro', label='Prediction', color = 'g')
ax.plot(GT,'^', label='Ground Truth', color = 'r' )

plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('b')
plt.title('test')

plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, 100, 5))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.legend()                
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the easiest and most understandable solution is to plot the respective lines between `pred` and `GT` in a loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1

#generate some random data
pred = np.random.rand(10)*70
GT =  pred+(np.random.randint(8,40,size= len(pred))*2.*(np.random.randint(2,size=len(pred))-.5 ))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

# plot a black line between the 
# ith prediction and the ith ground truth 
for i in range(len(pred)):
    ax.plot([i,i],[pred[i], GT[i]], c="k", linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(pred,'o', label='Prediction', color = 'g')
ax.plot(GT,'^', label='Ground Truth', color = 'r' )

ax.set_xlim((-1,10))
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('b')
plt.title('test')

plt.legend()             
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using matplotlib errorbar (http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html), with the idea of drawing error bars around the average of the two lines you are plotting:

Here is a minimal example to show my idea:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(0.1,10, 0.5)
y1 = pd.Series(np.exp(-x), index = x)
y2 = pd.Series(np.exp(-x)+ np.sin(x), index = x)
avg_line = (y1 + y2)*0.5

err = (avg_line - y1).abs()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
y1.plot(marker = 'o', label='Prediction', color = 'g', linestyle  = '', ax = ax)
y2.plot(marker = '^', label='Ground Truth', color = 'r', linestyle  = '', ax = ax)
ax.errorbar(x, avg_line.values, yerr=err.values, fmt= 'none', ecolor = 'k', barsabove = False, capthick=0)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax.legend()
```

Hope this solves your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can plot each line as a separate plot. You could make a loop and call `plot` for each line connecting the two points. However you could also give the `plot(x, y, ...)` two 2d arrays as arguments. Each column in `x` will correspond to the same column in `y` and are represented by a line in the plot. So you'll need to generate these two. It could look something like this:

```
L = len(pred)
t = np.c_[range(L), range(L)].T
ax.plot(t, np.c_[pred, GT].T, '-k')
```

Comment: I like this solution! Very compact! (However hard to understand for inexperienced people, I guess).

Comment: Thank you :) Yes it is not so readable. But the `c_` is a numpy function that generates a column array from the argument, and the `T` is the transpose function.